# Why my prepare statement function in MySQL doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to dynamic SQL stuff. I'm doing a certain task, and despite doing things just like presented on certain MySQL sites on Google, I encounter a syntax error. What might be wrong there? Thanks in advance. Applied solution is appreciated.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when field_key = ''',
      DAY(birth_date),
      ''' then field_value end) ',
      DAY(birth_date)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  employees;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT address, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM employees
                    GROUP BY address');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The actual error:

> 18:41:44  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,max(case when field_key = '10' then field_value end) 10,max(case when field_ke' at line 1    0.000 sec

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using integers as column aliases. This results in an error in any SQL, not just dynamic SQL:

```
mysql> select 'abc' 1, 'def' 2 from dual;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '1, 'def' 2 from dual' at line 1
```

You can fix this by using back-ticks around the aliases:

```
mysql> select 'abc' as `1`, 'def' as `2` from dual;
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   |
+-----+-----+
| abc | def |
+-----+-----+
```

Or by prefixing the alias with a non-digit character:

```
mysql> select 'abc' as day1, 'def' as day2 from dual;
+------+------+
| day1 | day2 |
+------+------+
| abc  | def  |
+------+------+

mysql> select 'abc' as _1, 'def' as _2 from dual;
+-----+-----+
| _1  | _2  |
+-----+-----+
| abc | def |
+-----+-----+
```

---

Re your comment:

Here is how you could put back-ticks around the aliases:

```
...
CONCAT(
  'max(case when field_key = ''',
  DAY(birth_date),
  ''' then field_value end) `',
  DAY(birth_date), '`'
)
...
```

Or add a prefix:

```
...
CONCAT(
  'max(case when field_key = ''',
  DAY(birth_date),
  ''' then field_value end) as day',
  DAY(birth_date)
)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's right, but it causes another questions regarding my code. I have to create 30 columns basing on days of birth, What would you recommend then? I would like to avoid standard "case when" solutions for each column of these 30, I think about changing the type of records in that particular column. Nevertheless - that's food for thought. Thanks once again!